# Reuse a Django_filter for multiple models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a very basic filter setup (using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) which allows me to query my data from my django rest api using date ranges:

```
/api/v2/metrics/?date=2017-01-01
/api/v2/metrics/?start=2017-03-03&end=2017-04-01
/api/v2/metrics/?start=2017-03-03
etc.
```

My filters look something like this:

```
class DateFilter(filters.FilterSet):
start = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='gte')
end = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='lte')
    class Meta:
        model = GaData
        fields = ['date']
```

And my API view sets are:

```
class GaDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GaData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GaDataSerializer
    filter_class = DateFilter

    def get_queryset(self): # This returns metrics only for the logged in user
        user_id = self.request.user.id
        return GaData.objects.filter(owner=user_id)

class CountriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = GaCountries.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GaCountriesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self): # This returns metrics only for the logged in user
        user_id = self.request.user.id
        return GaData.objects.filter(owner=user_id)
```

Now, the DateFilter is linked to the GaData model, I could re-write an identical filter and link it to my other model (GaCountries) but I think that there must be a better way, so that I don't need to write the same piece of code for each model.

How can I use a filter for multiple models, or can I simply somehow overwrite the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually create a base filter class for these situations

```
class BaseDateFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='gte')
    end = filters.DateFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='lte')

class GaDataFilter(BaseDateFilter):
    class Meta:
        model = GaData

class GaCountriesFilter(BaseDateFilter):
    class Meta:
        model = GaCountries
```